# AJAX forms partially works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I can submit a form like this and it works:

```
$(document).on('click', '#someLink', function() {
  var frm = $('#myCustomForm');
  frm.submit();
});
```

However, when I submit the same form like below, the form is not being submitted:

```
$(document).on('click', '#someLink', function() {
  var frm = $('#myCustomForm');
  frm.submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/comments/new/',
      dataType: 'application/json',
      data: frm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert('successful');
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert('something went wrong');
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you include code for your form?

Comment: frm.submit(function(e) {}) <--- that does NOT submit a form, that binds an event listener..... get rid of the `frm.submit(function(e) {` part.... just run the ajax code since you do not want to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

The two codes are complete opposites. frm.submit(function(e) {}) assigns a function to the form submission so you would need to submit the form again.

You just want to run the Ajax code so just run the code.

```
$(document).on('click', '#someLink', function(e) {
  var frm = $('#myCustomForm');
  $.ajax({
      ...
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I actually want to submit the form. Your code does not submit it. So how can I submit it? I need to submit the call using ajax call

Comment: why the ajax request is happening?

Comment: The form has NOTHING to do with the Ajax request....so not sure why you think you need to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your event handlers when the `document` is ready. Plus, `return false;` is enough for your `submit` handler.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  var frm = $('#myCustomForm');
  frm.on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/comments/new/',
      dataType: 'application/json',
      data: frm.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        alert('successful');
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert('something went wrong');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I think you should take a careful look at your url `/comments/new/` to make sure it's correct. Better still, simply get the `action` attribute of your form as the url instead.

```
url: frm.attr('action'),
```

Change that and see if it works.

Comment: I actually want to submit the form. Your code does not submit it. So how can I submit it? I need to submit the call using ajax call

Comment: why the ajax request is happening to url `/comments/new/`? There is no ajax request happening at all.

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk, if you get any alert (did you?) then ajax request request happened. It's an asynchronous request. So the page doesn't refresh like a normal submit